# I modified .db with sqlite, overwritten the original one in Android app and now the app doesn't launch

Tags: android, database, sqlite, replace

I wanted to modify a file.db of one app in an Android tablet. In its folder there are two .db files:

- file.db
- file.db-journal

I copied file.db on an USB key and opened it on my Mac with "db browser for SQlite".
I just modified a number of the data, saved and replaced in the original folder.

Now the app doesn't launch anymore, it says that has stopped.

I replaced again the file.db with the original one which I had the backup, but still the app it's not opening.

I guess the problem is not the edit of the database, but the replacement of the file. Somehow the app doesn't like it.

Comment: Hi Oliver. Why are you attempting to alter the database outside of the app?

Comment: You need to add the stack-trace for the failure. You may wish to refer to [Analyze a stack trace](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces) if you are not aware of how to obtain a stack-trace.